# Turn string "12/27/2020 00:00:00" into a date?

Tags: r, lubridate

String: `"12/27/2020 00:00:00"`

I'd like this to be formatted as a date. Tried:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time('12/27/2020 00:00:00', mdy)
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Then tried:

```
mdy('12/27/2020 00:00:00')
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Then tried:

```
as_date('12/27/2020 00:00:00')
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

How can I turn this string into a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `format` in `as.Date` from `base R` as

```
as.Date(str1, "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "2020-12-27"
```

---

Or if we need the `parse_date_time`, specify the `format` as a string

```
parse_date_time('12/27/2020 00:00:00',  'mdy HMS')
#[1] "2020-12-27 UTC"
```

To convert to `Date` class, wrap with `as.Date` or `as_date`

```
as_date(parse_date_time('12/27/2020 00:00:00',  'mdy HMS'))
#[1] "2020-12-27"
```

Or

```
mdy_hms('12/27/2020 00:00:00')
#[1] "2020-12-27 UTC"
```

With the `format` in `tidyverse`, it needs to match the full format.  Here, we have Hour:Minute:Seconds as well, so we need the `_hms`

---

Or this can be automatically picked up with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
anydate('12/27/2020 00:00:00')
#[1] "2020-12-27"
```

Comment: Thanks. Using tidyverse format with `mdy_hms` is it possibel to then extract just the date part and have it formatted as a date? i.e. drop the hms?

Comment: @DougFir After doing the `parse_date_time`, you can wrap with `as.Date` or `as_date`